# Exhaustively iterate over all values in string union?

Tags: typescript

I have a string union like this:

`export type Intervals = 'total' | 'weekly' | 'biweekly' | 'monthly' | 'annually';`

I want to display these to the user by looping over an array of the union's values:

```
const intervals = ['total', 'weekly', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'annually'];
intervals.forEach(...);
```

How can I type the `intervals` array such that it's guaranteed to have all of the values of the `Intervals` union?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of deriving the array from the type, derive the type from the array.

```js
export const INTERVALS = ['total', 'weekly', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'annually'] as const;

const temp = [...INTERVALS];
export type Interval = typeof temp[0];
```

Comment: even easier: `export type Interval = typeof INTERVALS[number];`

Comment: what does the "number" signify in this line?

Comment: I don't get this. `temp` is just a shallow copy of the original array and `temp[0]` is the first element of that array, which is `'total'` and `typeof temp[0]` should then be just `string`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to make sure that `intervals` must be assignable to `Array<Intervals>`:

```
const intervalsMisspelled: Array<Intervals> = 
  ['weekly', 'biweekly', 'annually', 'monthly', 'totul']; // error, "totul"
```

But that doesn't prevent you from leaving things out:

```
const intervalsMissing: Array<Intervals> = 
  ['weekly', 'biweekly', 'annually', 'monthly']; // oops, no error but missing "total"
```

To fix that, you can make a helper function called `ensureArray()` which takes a type parameter `T` (which will be `Intervals` for you) and then returns a new function which takes a list of parameters of type `T` and infers an array type `A` for that list.  If the elements of the `A` array (`A[number]`) are of a narrower type than `T`, then you must have left something out and you should get an error.  Here's a way to do that:

```
const ensureArray = <T>() => <A extends T[]>(
  ...a: A & ([T] extends [A[number]] ? A : never)
): A => a;

const ensureIntervalsArray = ensureArray<Intervals>();

const intervals = ensureIntervalsArray(
  'annually', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'total', 'weekly'); // okay

const intervalsMisspelled = ensureIntervalsArray(
  'annually', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'totul', 'weekly'); // error, "totul"

const intervalsMissing = ensureIntervalsArray(
  'annually', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'weekly'); // error,
// [string, string, string, string] is not assignable to never
```

This works, although the error you get on `intervalsMissing` is fairly cryptic, saying that something isn't assignable to `never`, without telling you what the problem really is.  Since TypeScript doesn't currently let us make [custom type errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), we can only try to work around that.

The following gives an even more weird error message but it gives the developer a hint:

```
const ensureArray = <T>() => <A extends T[]>(
  ...a: A & ([T] extends [A[number]] ? A :
    { errorMessage: [Error, "You are missing", Exclude<T, A[number]>] })
): A => a;

const ensureIntervalsArray = ensureArray<Intervals>();

const intervalsMissing = ensureIntervalsArray(
  'annually', 'biweekly', 'monthly', 'weekly'); // error,
// Property 'errorMessage' is missing in type 
// '["annually", "biweekly", "monthly", "weekly"]' 
// but required in type '{ errorMessage: [Error, "You are missing", "total"]; }'
```

Hopefully one of those is sufficient for your needs.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I type the intervals array such that it's guaranteed to have all of the values of the Intervals union

Not easily. You can declare it as a union of *tuples*. Say you only have `'total' | 'weekly'`, you could then do:

```
const intervals: 
| ['total', 'weekly']
| ['weekly', 'total']
```

What you have here is a permutation `nPn`.